# Vite.js renames CSS class names. How to then use class names in CSS selectors?

Tags: css, vite

I have this code:

```
import styles from "../styles/dragdrop.module.css";
(...)

return ( 
        <div className={styles.dragDrop}></div>
    );
```

After building the project with vite, the code looks like this:

```
<div class="_dragDrop_d8kak_45"></div>
```

(the CSS classname has changed from **dragDrop** to **_dragDrop_d8kak_45**).

But I'm using CSS selectors in my front-end JS to do stuff with those divs:

```
const targetBox = e.target.closest(".dragDrop");
```

My frontend js doesn't work anymore.

I could perhaps start using css selectors like div[class*="dragDrop"], but it seems like a bad idea.

How is this done properly?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have disabled the renaming of CSS class names by adding this into my vite.config.js.

```
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    modules: {
      localsConvention: "camelCase",
      generateScopedName: "[local]"
    }
  },
(...)
```